# Why doesn't translateX work as expected for fixed elements on IE9, IE10, and IE11?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, css-position

I'm trying to achieve the following in IE9, IE10, and IE11 (works perfectly on Chrome and FF):

In mobile mode, I have a main `#container` wrapper that holds the entire site contents and a nav side menu div which is inside the `#container` (cannot be moved out, btw), yet is not visible and is hidden off-screen. When a user clicks a menu open toggle button, it should slide the `#container` to the right, revealing the nav side menu div directly positioned to its left. The "sliding" is happening using translateX, which gets assigned as soon as the "open" class gets applied to it via the toggle. In the IEs, I'm getting the animation part as expected, but without a visible side nav (empty space only).

```
#container {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    transition: transform ease .5s;
    width: 100%;
}
#container.open {
    position: fixed;
    transform: translateX(300px);
}

#nav-side-menu {
    left: -300px;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: scroll;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 300px;
}
```

Comment: Can you link to a demo? I took the liberty [to make one](http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/vxntq8b1/); does it reflect your scenario accurately?

Comment: Perfect! Illustrates the scenario exactly as intended.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem here is with the use of `position: fixed` *inside* a transformed element. Per the specification, when using fixed-positioned elements *...the containing block is established by the viewport.* [There is a debate](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-transforms/#issue-3de43ef4) as to whether transformed elements should be the containing block of fixed descendants, but Internet Explorer doesn't presently support this.

In this particular instance you could avoid the cross-browser complications by avoiding CSS Transforms altogether. Instead, try moving the containing element laterally using the `left` property. Below is my markup — which I believe to be a reasonable reflection of yours:

```html
<article>
    <nav>
        <p>This is the navigation portion.</p>
    </nav>
    <section>
        <p>This is the content portion.</p>
    </section>
</article>
```

As described above, the following approach makes key use of a relatively positioned container, moved side-to-side by transitioning (supported since IE10) the `left` property. We're also using the `calc` function (supported since IE9) to determine better dimensions and offsets:

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

article {
    left: -300px;
    position: relative;
    transition: left 2s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: calc(100% + 300px);
    padding: 0 1em 0 calc(300px + 1em);
}

article.open {
    left: 0px;
}

nav {
    position: fixed;
    width: 300px; height: 100%;
    margin: -1em auto auto calc(-300px - 1em);
}
```

This approach yields a more consistent experience across both Internet Explorer, Chrome, and Firefox. The end-result can be viewed online here: http://jsfiddle.net/jonathansampson/vxntq8b1/

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response. Makes perfect sense now. However, I'm not able to move the nav outside the container because the same nav in desktop mode is used inside the container like a regular desktop nav. I am using CSS only to transform that same desktop nav into a side nav for mobile. Nice demo btw!

Comment: @DecafJava How about positioning the nav absolutely, and not positioning the parent element at all? http://jsfiddle.net/vxntq8b1/4/

Comment: @DecafJava If you have markup requirements and restrictions, please share those in your question above.

Comment: @DecafJava there's no point in briefing half of what you require. If you only ask for half then that's quite rightly what you should get.

Comment: The only restriction is that I cannot move the nav from inside the container to outside. Therefore, unfortunately the sibling idea strategy won't be applicable. :-(

Comment: I got pretty close making it absolute instead of fixed, though the only problem is the height. It ends up taking up only about 400 pixels of height (natural content height) and the height 100% is not respected. I want it to spread all the way down to full browser height like it did when it was fixed. Also, by making it absolute, I had to remove the overflow: hidden from a body.open class I had applied (which I had added so that while nav is open, users can't drag their fingers around the rest of the page).

Comment: @morganFeeney I don't think I left out any critical pieces.

Comment: @DecafJava you can use absolute positioning but you'll need to ensure you use top: 0; bottom: 0; and make a wrapping, relatively positioned. element 100% in height. A great example is the WordPress admin side menu.

Comment: JonathanSampson and morganFeeney: problem solved. As you guys suggested, the key was to use absolute positioning instead and from the parent remove the positioning (defaults to static) so that 100% height can work. Also, the bottom 0 was needed, too. Thanks!

Comment: @JonathanSampson I love it when a plan comes together. Glad you got it working.

Comment: Oops I meant @DecafJava

Comment: @DecafJava I've updated my answer to include an approach that works best across modern browsers. It avoids some of the uncertain behavior that we get with transformed parents and fixed descendants in some browsers.

Comment: @JonathanSampson ah, using the left property. This is the original route I took but the team decided to use transform instead for the benefits of hardware acceleration. In most cases, I'm sure it's a solid approach, though.

Comment: @DecafJava Hardware-acceleration isn't really an issue here. You're moving an element side-to-side 300 pixels :) By using transformations you're going to promote the transformed element to a containing blog and opt yourself into some fairly problematic edge cases as far as the rendering model is concerned.

Comment: @JonathanSampson Good point. lol. Thank you for clearing up that false perception.

Comment: The downside to this approach is that it's more work for the browser. Transitioning the `left` property will trigger a layout, paint and composition. If IE was able to use transform with fixed position elements, then by using transform you only have a composition change, no repaint or re-layout needed. More info on performance costs of these attributes are at http://csstriggers.com/

Comment: Yeah, on mobile browsers I have found the performance of `transition: left` and similar to be poor. See e.g. [here](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/why-moving-elements-with-translate-is-better-than-posabs-topleft/) for some discussion as to why, and see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4749765/927046) for an example using Mondernizr to provide a fall-back for browsers which do not support CSS3 transforms.