# Target IE11 on specific screen sizes using CSS Media queries

Tags: css, less, media-queries, internet-explorer-11

I'm having some issues with IE11 similar [to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27952725/why-doesnt-translatex-work-as-expected-for-fixed-elements-on-ie9-ie10-and-ie1). I have a menu that expands at a certain size (1440px) and breaks in IE11. Using Media Queries I can target IE11 using `(-ms-high-contrast: none), (-ms-high-contrast: active)`. However, I only want this at a certain resolution (> 1440px ).

I've tried various combinations of

`@media screen and (min-width: 1440px) and (-ms-high-contrast: none) and (-ms-high-contrast: active)`

But they don't seem to work

How to target and element in IE11 at screen size `> 1440px` without affecting the other browsers or using JS.

Comment: @SureshPonnukalai Yep! Found that one a minute ago. Added the answer in this post too.

Answer (score 0):

**Using CSS:**

```
@media(min-width: 1440px){
  .element{
    -ms-high-contrast: none;
  }
}

@media(max-width: 1440px){
  .element{
    -ms-high-contrast: active;
  }
}
```

***Remember that*** @media can also be used for print interfaces, so @media screen is simply specifying that these rules are to be implemented when displaying on a screen, but not when printing. @media by itself is more broad, and would apply to print.

**Using jQuery:**

if you want plain js you can translate it:
$( window ).width();
or
$( document ).width();
(use one or another depending on the behaviour you need)
you can programatically check screen sixze with:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      if($(window).width() > 1440){
         $('.element').addClass('msClass');
      }else{
         if($('.element').hasClass('msClass'){
              $('.element').addClass('msClass');
         }
      }
});
```

This only works when document loads, but you can add a dynamic function with:

```
//Window resize event listener, you'll need to put the other function first if you want it to being applied when you load the view.
      $(window).resize(function(){
              //if the actual window width is greater than 1440...
              if($(window).width() > 1440){
                 //add a class to the desired element/s (this class must include the changes you want when more than 1440p)
                 $('.element').addClass('msClass');
                 //if the screen resizes below 1440p...
              }else{
                 //if the class is set before
                 if($('.element').hasClass('msClass'){
                      //remove this class
                      $('.element').addClass('msClass');
                 }
              }
        });
```

You must create a class called msClass if you follow this example, where you put whatever you want to happen when >1440p.

Element is related to the element class (you can even use an id with $('#element') specifically set at the element/s you want to take this behaviour).

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer, but as explained in the question I'm trying to solve this without JS/jQuery

Comment: i'm sorry but CSS is not a programming language so it can't check conditionally -ms-high-contrast, you only can check screen width.
Have you tried to do (edit post)

Comment: I'm not sure what you were trying to solve with your edit as -ms-high-contrast is not what I'm trying to achieve. Thanks for the input tho! I've just posted the answer I found somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

After searching through the depths of Stack Overflow I managed [to find someone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45974217/4970028) with the same problem.

Using:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1440px) { 
   _:-ms-fullscreen, :root .THECLASSNAME { width: 575px; } 
}
```

Made it work.